# Macro magic need to be explained C++

Tags: c++

I've encountered with this code, can someone enlighten me how it works?

```
    #define MACRO_CLASS( Class_Name ) \
                                            \
    public:                                 \
       some public things                   \
                                            \
    private:                                \
       Class_Name();                        \
      ~Class_Name();                        \
                                            \
```

and then this macro used within other class

```
    class __declspec(dllexport)  Class: A,B,C
    {
    public:
         ....
         MACRO_CLASS( Class )//What happens over here?
         ....
    }
```

Does MACRO_CLASS imports all of his stuff in Class or something else happens?

Comment: You may want to invest a bit of time understanding how the C pre-processor works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor.

Comment: The person that wrote this macro is really lazy, apparently, and likes obscuring things through abstraction.

Comment: Fire the person that made this macro and delete it from your source control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MACRO_CLASS` is a macro that expands out to the text specified, so:

```
class Class {
    MACRO_CLASS(Class)
```

...would expand out to:

```
class Class {
    public:
        some public things
    private:
        Class();
        ~Class();
```

IOW, at least as you've shown it, it declares the default ctor and dtor private. This will prevent normal construction of objects of that class--for the class to be used, you'd typically also include a public, static function that creates an object of that class (e.g., like a singleton).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct, the interface that is shown in the Macro is added to the actual class. Using the macro results in a constructor, a destructor, and all the public variables that are defined in the macro.

For example, suppose you had a `class A` and you used the macro. The preprocessor would expand this to:

```
class A
{
// BEGIN macro expansion
public:
    some public things

private:
    A();
    ~A();
// END macro expansion
};
```

The stuff between the comments is macro generated.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Not sure why--it's correct.